# Using option value to set a variable for search criteria

Tags: mysql

In a .class.php file, I have this query.

```
public function findschedules($arricao, $depicao, $airline, $aircraft)   {
    $query = "SELECT db_schedules.*, db_aircraft.name AS aircraft, db_aircraft.registration
            FROM db_schedules, db_aircraft
            WHERE db_schedules.depicao LIKE '$depicao'
            AND db_schedules.arricao LIKE '$arricao'
            AND db_schedules.code LIKE '$airline'
            AND db_schedules.aircraft LIKE '$aircraft'
            AND db_aircraft.id LIKE '$aircraft'
            AND db_schedules.enabled = '1'
            AND db_schedules.daysofweek LIKE '%{$day}%'";
    return DB::get_results($query);
}
```

The public function is used when carrying out the search. However, the file links to a template file `$this->show('airport_search.tpl');` which has all the HTML code, and inside it, the select box.

```
<select style="border:1px solid #DCDCDC; color:#003663; font-size:11px;" class="search" name="day" id="day">
                <option value="0">Sunday</option>
                <option value="1">Monday</option>
                <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
                <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
                <option value="4">Thursday</option>
                <option value="5">Friday</option>
                <option value="6">Saturday</option>
            </select>
```

The line below is designed to search for part of a string in `daysofweek` column of `db_schedules` table. I am trying to assign a variable to it, from the select box in `airport_search.tpl`. I'd like ideally to gain the variable out of `option value=""` and assign it in the query.

```
AND db_schedules.daysofweek LIKE '%{$day}%'";
```

Additionally, `daysofweek` column is a varchar(7) type field, with a default value of `0123456`. They stand for days, 0 is a Sunday, 1-6 Monday-Saturday. So the query's intended output is to look for the day given by the user in the select box.

How do I assign the variable from the option box into the query, based on user input in the select box in another file?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$day = $_POST['day'];
```

is all you need to get the `value` attribute from the selected option of the form once it is submitted.

However, don't use `$day`.  Use mysqli/PDO and write parameterized queries like so:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("...AND daysofweek LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute("%$day%");
```

Comment: Apologies for my incompetence, however I never worked with `$_POST` and `pdo` before, would you not mind clarifying it a bit more, and where should it be ideally used for it to work?

Comment: @zzwyb89 you don't have to do anything special to set up `$_POST`.  It's automatically unserialized by PHP when you submit a request with the POST method.  If you're just submitting a form with `method=post` you can use it.  `PDO` is not difficult to use at all, especially if you already know how to use `ext/mysql`.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: What would I have to do to include an 'All Days' option? The intended output would be simply all records in the table.

Comment: @zzwyb89 You would have to check whether `$_POST['day']` is `'ALL'` (or whatever value you decide).  Then, run the same query without the `daysofweek` parameter.

Comment: I'm trying now to make it with a second variable as well, but it doesn't return any results: http://pastebin.com/5PDBRUpu